# Android media player progress bar rest to "0" when stop music

Tags: android, progress-bar, media-player

I put one song into an app (tabhost) and I have progress bar, play button, stop button, loop button.

The function I want is:

- when user plays the music, the progress bar starts to run from "0"
- when user presses *stop*, the progress bar stops at where it was, waits for the user to press *play* again, and then continues where it left off

I might change the button name to "pause" later, but this is the function I need right now.

Right now, 2 issues:

1. When *stop* is pressed, the progress bar returns to "0", but  the music resumes playing from where it left off (music not playing from very beginning)
2. The progress bar runs faster than desired; it runs to the end before the music ending.

Here is my code, hope someone could help thank you so much:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public class TabMusicActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean playing = false;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    int progress = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_music);

        final ImageButton buttonStart = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                if (!playing) {
                    playing = true;
                    buttonStart.setImageResource(R.drawable.music_stop_button);
                    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+ R.raw.bashibafo);

                    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(TabMusicActivity.this, path);
                    }
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        process();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    playing = false;
                    buttonStart.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);

                    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        mediaPlayer.pause();

                    }
                }

            }
        });



        ImageButton buttonLoop = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonLoop);
        buttonLoop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void process (){
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progress = 0;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (progress < 100){
                    progress = doWork();
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    handler.post( new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private int doWork(){
        progress++;
        if (progress < 100){
            return progress;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this code for playing music

```
 if (player != null)
        {
            player.seekTo(length);
            player.start();
        }
        else
        {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.fromFile(new File(url)));

            seek_bar.setMax(player.getDuration());

            seek_bar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());

            player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                {
                    player.reset();
                    player.release();
                    player = null;
                    seekHandler.removeCallbacks(run);
                    seek_bar.setProgress(0);
                    if (recieveOrSend.equals("send"))
                    {

                        holder.iv_audio_pause_send.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.iv_audio_play_send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        holder.iv_audio_pause_recieve.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.iv_audio_play_recieve.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });

            //          player.prepare();
            player.start();

        }
        seekUpdation();
```

Methods--

```
    Runnable run = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        seekUpdation();
    }
};

public void seekUpdation()
{
    seek_bar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
    seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
}

private void pausePlayer()
{

    try
    {
        if (player != null)
        {
            player.pause();
            length = player.getCurrentPosition();
            seekHandler.removeCallbacks(run);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```